# is it possible to configure the react 18 use jsx in development and production environment

Tags: reactjs, vite

Now I am using vite `v4.3.5` to compile the typescript project, normally, the react `"react": "^18.2.0"` use jsxdev in the development environment, use jsx in the production environment. is it possible to make the react use jsx in development and production environment? I have configure the jsx in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"jsx": "react-jsx",
```

and the `vite.config.ts` like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({
    jsxRuntime: "automatic"
  })],
})
```

but now in production mode, the react use jsxDev function to render the page. Am I missing something? what should I do to force use the jsx? I did not found any configuration about jsxDev in my app, why the production environment load the jsxDev configuration?